# Perl6: does `dir` from IO::Path decode the filenames always the right way?

Tags: io, raku

Does the function `dir` from [IO::Path](https://doc.perl6.org/type/IO::Path) decode the file-names automatically the right way or is there a possibility to set the encoding?

---

In Perl5 I mostly follow the recommendation to decode the input and to encode the output.

So for example in Perl5 I would write something like this, if the encoding the OS uses to write the file-names is different from the encoding of the console output.

```
use Encode::Locale;
use Encode qw(decode);
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(console_out)';

my @files;
while ( my $file = readdir $dh ) {
    push @files, decode( 'locale_fs', $file );
}
for my $file ( @files ) {
     print "$file\n";
}
```

In Perl6 I don't know exactly what I should do.

Comment: Could you please share some code demonstrating what you are doing and how you would expect it to behave and suggest what your worries are with "encoding"? Without some code, this seems more like a question to ask on [#perl6](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=perl6&nick=). Even there, some code wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms: I have extended the question.

Comment: on win32, the unicode winapi functions are used, on non-windows, utf8 is assumed (cf https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/2f3c7dd3a5a831d072fd27f2eadf74d3dcaef8b8/src/io/dirops.c#L296); as can be seen from that snippet, the ability to set a different encoding in principle exists at the lowest level, but is does not appear to be exposed to the user in any way...

Comment: @Christoph: Could you put your comment in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl 6 uses Unicode strings internally (in a grapheme-based representation), and coding happens at the IO boundaries.

For console output, you can manually set the encoding via `$*OUT.encoding("...")`.

For directory listings, it depends on the backend: With the JVM, it *should* do the right things (or fail the same way Java does). With MoarVM, it will depend on the platform: On Win32, the Unicode API is used (which, again, *should* do the right thing), whereas on other platforms, [UTF-8 is assumed](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/2f3c7dd3a5a831d072fd27f2eadf74d3dcaef8b8/src/io/dirops.c#L296). As can be seen from that snippet, the ability to use a different encoding in principle exists at the lowest level, but it does not appear to be exposed to the user in any way...